# How to remove padding while reading a file as bytes

Tags: java, file

i have this code that read from a file and return an array of bytes:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {        

 // Get the size of the file
   long length = file.length();

   // You cannot create an array using a long type.
   // It needs to be an int type.
   // Before converting to an int type, check
   // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
   if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
       // File is too large
       throw new IOException("File is too large!");
   }

   // Create the byte array to hold the data
   byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

   // Read in the bytes
   int offset = 0;
   int numRead = 0;

   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
   try {
       while (offset < bytes.length
              && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
           offset += numRead;
       }
   } finally {
       is.close();
   }

   // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
   if (offset < bytes.length) {
       throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
   }
   return bytes;
   }
```

Someone can explain how can i remove the padding in the file before the byte conversion?

Comment: What is the padding that you're trying to remove?

Comment: I was trying to read the file as a block of text without any space between words and lines (without any space in general). And i want read this block of text without any space ,as a vector of bytes.

At the moment i have only this function to read a file as a vector or bytes

Comment: So you should probably read it as text, using a `FileReader` not a `FileInputStream`, then remove the spaces and any other unwanted characters, and lastly turn it into bytes.

Comment: There is no way to do this with FileInputStream? Because i don't have the charset of that text file and i need to read as bytes.

Comment: If your program doesn't know the charset, how can  it possibly know which bytes in the file represent spaces and other unwanted characters?

Comment: Ok my mistake... Charset is known. I've tried the FileReader but with the trim function some space remain, and i don't understand why.

Comment: If you want to remove all whitespace, then the `trim` method is not ideal.  I would recommend using `replaceAll`, with a suitable regular expression such as `"\\s"`.